# activity reference in model

Tags: android, firebase, mvvm

I'm using MVVM pattern with firebase as a backend in my app. Firebase Phone authentication is present too and as it should it's placed in the model which is a singleton. The process of signing in needs an activity reference for callback binding but creating a reference to the activity might lead to memory leaks since it's in a singleton class and it's not generally a good practice as I doubt. Should I put this logic in the activity or is there a better approach for this?

That's the method that needs the activity reference:

```
void phoneLogin(String number) {

        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                number,        // Phone number to verify
                1,                  // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.MINUTES,   // Unit of timeout
---->           activty             // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks


    }
```

Comment: "it's placed in the model which is a singleton" - why is your model a singleton?

Comment: Because it's where firebase stuff is going. Shouldn't I do so to prevent multiple connectionns going on to firebase?

Comment: You can check one of my repos where I have implemented [Firebase auth](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp-Clean-Architecture-MVVM/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebaseapp/auth/AuthActivity.java) together with a [ViewModel](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp-Clean-Architecture-MVVM/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebaseapp/auth/AuthViewModel.java) and a [Repository](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp-Clean-Architecture-MVVM/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebaseapp/auth/AuthRepository.java).

Comment: The authentication doesn't take place with phone number is with Google but I think it can help you get the idea.

Comment: Alex I already went through your repo when researching firebase and mvvm and it did help with the general idea thanks

Answer (score 0):

That was good challenge. I think best way is to create a `LiveData` in your singleton class. So your activity can observe this `LiveData` change and on it's change verify your phone and then in callback call your singleton class method for verify callback handling

Comment: That'll work but i think it looks a bit ugly, I'll spend some more time on this and if I ended up doing so I'll verify your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Hadi this is what I found any where for using sending data from viewmodel to view in mvvm and you will found this too